# Download asset file from asset in Azure media service

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-media-services

I have an issue. I have an asset in the azure media service. The asset contains an asset file. I would like to know how to download the asset file. I'm using httparty gem for this.

```
HTTParty.get(https://<host>.restv2.<location>.media.azure.net/api/Files('<file_id>'), headers: headers)
```

The headers have the authorization value. The above request gives the metadata of the asset file but I would like to download the asset file. Can anyone please help. Thanks. I have gone through the below documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/assetfile

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a SAS [locator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/locator#create_a_locator) for the parent asset which will return a SAS URL for the asset, something like:

https://[storageaccount].blob.core.windows.net/asset-[parentAssetId]?[queryparams]

Sending a GET request with the asset file name appended to the SAS URL will return the assetfile contents:

GET https://[storageaccount].blob.core.windows.net/asset-[parentAssetId]/[**assetFileName**]?[queryparams]

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-deliver-asset-download) is a .NET example. You can ignore the job reference bits and it should work with any asset.

I also find it very helpful to use the [Azure Media Services Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer) along with Fiddler to figure out the REST requests needed for different workflows.