# How to download video from Azure Media Services

Tags: video, download, azure-media-services

Can we download video embedded on a website made using Microsoft Azure media services?

This is link of website: 
https://sjphysics.azurewebsites.net

This is its video link: 
`blob:https://sjphysics.azurewebsites.net/94c9b7aa-229a-4595-9dd2-9d623fb3f8cc`.

Comment: The question body does not explain the question. Please, do a better explanation. The link does not go anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Storage APIs to create SAS URLs in Azure Media Services V3.

You can refer to the below posts.

[1. Azure Media Services v3 shared access policy for download link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364184/azure-media-services-v3-shared-access-policy-for-download-link)

[2. Download asset file from asset in Azure media service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982254/download-asset-file-from-asset-in-azure-media-service)

**Suggestions for New Users.**

Before you ask questions, you can search the answer in stackoverflow like below screenshot.

[image]